# Cannot install Guest Additions on Windows 7 host, Windows 8 guest

Tags: virtualbox

I've installed VirtualBox 4.1.18 on my 64-bit Windows 7 Professional SP1 machine.  The guest is running x64 Windows 8 Enterprise.

I've read in numerous places that to get the guest to take up more than a fraction of my screen I need to install Guest Additions via the guest window Devices menu > Install Guest Additions...

When I try to do this, however, nothing happens.  No error messages, no dialog box of any kind.  Absolutely nothing.  I might as well be clicking on the title bar of the window or something.

I can see VBoxGuestAdditions.iso in the VirtualBox installation folder on the host machine.  I tried manually mounting it to the CD/DVD drive of the guest but that made no difference.  Two posts I came across said explicitly not to mount it, so in the guest window I then selected Devices > CD/DVD Devices > Remove disk from virtual drive.  Didn't make any difference either.

Is this a problem with running Windows 8 as a guest or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How long did you wait? In my experience, it can take a fair amount of time for the ISO to mount.

Comment: After you hit "Install Guest Additions", and before you unmounted the drive, did you check the Guest system to see if it was reading the ISO?  Windows 8 may be set by default to not perform AutoPlay/Autorun, so you might have to manually run the setup after the ISO is mounted.

Comment: Windows 8 is not an officially supported client under VirtualBox right now. Initial support is slated for version 4.2, which is currently at Beta 1.

Comment: I found a [SysProbs](http://www.sysprobs.com/install-windows-8-release-preview-on-virtualbox-working-guest-additions-tools) article that explained I had to go into the guest OS and run Guest Additions from there.  I did so, it didn't auto run but it was pretty obvious which executable the auto-run would have executed so I ran that.  It did something but I didn't see a normal installer.  The VM went black. Now when I start the guest the guest window appears but the VM is completely black.  No indication Windows 8 is running at all.  I think I'll restore the VM from backup and wait for VB 4.2.

Answer (score 7):

1. **Devices** → **CD/DVD Devices** → **Remove disk from virtual drive**
2. Check your connectivity if you can reach out
3. **Devices menu** → **Install Guest Additions**